# 'call' instruction being called with 2 parameters

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I have disassembled a simple D script (unlinked) and I can find this weird piece of assembly (Intel Syntax)

```
call   1e <_Dmain+0x1e>
```

From my understanding `call` pushes the current stack base pointer to the stack and jumps to the address it received as a parameter.

This `call` instruction seems to take 2 parameters though. What's up with that?

Full Function:

```
0000000000000000 <_Dmain>:
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 8b ec                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   48 83 ec 10             sub    rsp,0x10
   8:   c7 45 f8 05 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x5
   f:   c7 45 f8 06 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x6
  16:   48 89 ef                mov    rdi,rbp
  19:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   1e <_Dmain+0x1e>
  1e:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  20:   c9                      leave  
  21:   c3                      ret    
  22:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

Comment: `<_Dmain+0x1e>` is probably just an annotation by the disassembler saying that the address `1e` corresponds to offset 0x1e within `_Dmain`.

Comment: These are not two arguments. The `<_Dmain+0x1e>` thing is just the address of the call interpreted in terms of the debugged executable.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Then wouldn't that just call the next operation (1e)?

Comment: @JeroenBollen : Yes, it would. That's peculiar. :)

Answer (score 2):

The call instruction only takes one operand, and it's a nondescriptive address. The disassembler is trying to be nice and find a symbol for the call target. The address is 1e, there's no symbol right there, so the disassembler finds the closest symbol (_Dmain) and gives you the offset from that. It's not a second argument, it's a hint for you.

Comment: Wouldn't 1e be the next operation though?

Comment: It is. If you look closely, the inline offset in the CALL command encodiing is all zeros. The offset is relative to the command after the CALL. What's the point of such weird call, I have no no idea. Probably a pipeline flush or something.

Comment: Because OP mentions the script was not linked, the zero offset is to reserve space for a relocation. When the script is actually linked, whatever symbol that call is supposed to refer to will be used to calculate the actual offset for the `call` instruction.